# Selective checkout

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a small c++ header-only utilities library that is roughly organized like hits:

```
my_lib_root\
   - my_lib    # actual library headers
   - test_src  # unit test files
   - proj      # project files for the unit tests and development (e.g. visual studio solution file)
   - ...       # some more files like readme, ci config, clang_format ...
```

When I want to use it in another project, I usually just add this library as a submodule and add `my_lib_root` to the include paths (so I can access the headers via `#include <my_lib/header1.h>`):

```
my_app\
   - libs\
       - my_lib_root\
            - my_lib
            - test_src
            - ...
   - src
   - ...
```

However, this pulls in a lot of stuff, which is only relevant when I'm doing the actual development of my_lib, so I wonder, **if there is a way to only checkout the `my_lib` subfolder**:

```
my_app\
   - libs\
       - my_lib_root\
            - my_lib                
   - src
   - ...
```

Ideally, I'd even like to get rid of `my_lib_root`completely:

```
my_app\
   - libs\         
       - my_lib                
   - src
   - ...
```

Is there any way in git to achieve one of the above two results?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using sparse-checkout.

There is a already a question about this in SO. Check this out. [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/13738951#13738951)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Sparse checkout will not allow me to achieve the second version though - right?